# Laravel setting up from local to production : change config settings

Tags: laravel

I am trying to move my site from local to production.

I noticed that the bootstrap/cache/config.php file has many setting for my local host eg:

```
'file' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'file',
        'path' => '/var/www/storage/framework/cache/data',
      ),

 array (
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => '/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log',
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
      ),
```

do I have manually change these settings or is there a command. i cannot find anything on it.

my path setting is now:

```
/home/project/public_html/laravel/storage
```

EDIT:

i tried running the following commands from root of site:

```
php artisan config:clear 
and 
php artisan cache:clear)
```

but my **bootstrap/cache/config.php**  still has the following paths:

```
array (
      'local' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/var/www/storage/app',
      ),
```

Would it help if i deleted the folders ?

This is the error:

```
There is no existing directory at "/var/www/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied
```

Comment: You can use `php artisan config:cache` to re-read the `.env` settings and cache the config. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to delete the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. Leave it as it is.

---

The error says it all.

> There is no existing directory at "/var/www/storage/logs" and its not
>   buildable: **Permission denied**

Make sure the `storage` directory has `0655` or `0665` or `drwxr-xr-x` permission.

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, clear the cache,config,route.

You should run the following commands:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```